# 'break' is creating not properly in loop pylint(not-in-loop) error

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to make a calculator and to specify first number I think I need to break the loop but it just gives me an error('break' not properly in loop)

```
def solve():
    global equation
    global n1
    equation = input("Enter Equation( Do not leave spaces nor =) ")
    equationlist = list(equation)
    length = len(equationlist)
    n1 = ''
    n2 = ''
    op = ''
    equals = ''
    for i in range(0,length):
        numbercheck = True
        try:
            int(equationlist[i])
        except ValueError:
            numbercheck = False
    a = equationlist[i]
    a = str(a)
    if numbercheck == True:
        n1 += a
    elif numbercheck==False:
        op = equationlist[i]
        solve2()
        break
```

Comment: The error is clear, you're adding a `break` instruction outside of a loop (if/elif is not considered a loop).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be a problem with indentation, the code starting at line a = `equationlist[i]` needs to be at the same indent level as try and catch as shown below ( doing so will make the block part of the `for` loop)

```
def solve():
    global equation
    global n1
    equation = input("Enter Equation( Do not leave spaces nor =) ")
    equationlist = list(equation)
    length = len(equationlist)
    n1 = ''
    n2 = ''
    op = ''
    equals = ''
    for i in range(0,length):
        numbercheck = True
        try:
            int(equationlist[i])
        except ValueError:
            numbercheck = False
        a = equationlist[i]
        a = str(a)
        if numbercheck == True:
            n1 += a
        elif numbercheck==False:
            op = equationlist[i]
            solve2()
            break
```